# How would I implement a fixed size List in Scala?

Tags: scala

For example suppose I want a list that contains 0 up to a max of 1000 elements. Above this, the oldest insertions should be dropped first. Do collections support this functionality natively? If not how would I go about the implementation? I understand that certain operations are very slow on Lists so maybe I need a different data type?

Looking at an element should not affect the list. I would like insert and size operations only.

Comment: 1. Do you remove a (regular) element of the list when you look at it ? (I'm looking at size-bounded queues) 2. Do you have an idea of the operations you *do* need ?

Comment: Amended with extra information

Comment: Don't you need to *look* at list elements ? At all ? If so, do you want to start looking at the head of the list (the last one you entered ?), the tail (the oldest element ?) or any element, accessed through its index ?

Comment: I don't need to look at the elements. Once per day I need to do a sort and then I look at the highest ranking. Before that I do many many inserts and so I need this portion to be very efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want a size-bounded queue. Here's a similar question: [Maximum Length for scala queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918731/maximum-length-for-scala-queue/6920366#6920366)

There are three solutions presented in that question. You can,

1. Write a queue from scratch (paradigmatic gave code for this),
2. Extend Scala's [Queue](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#package) implementation by subclassing, or
3. Use the typeclass extension pattern (aka, "pimp my library") to extend Scala's `Queue`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my first pass implementation in case someone else find it useful

```
import scala.collection._
import mutable.ListBuffer

class FixedList[A](max: Int) extends Traversable[A] {

  val list: ListBuffer[A] = ListBuffer()

  def append(elem: A) {
    if (list.size == max) {
      list.trimStart(1)
    }
    list.append(elem)
  }

  def foreach[U](f: A => U) = list.foreach(f)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A circular array is the fastest implementation. It's basically an array with a read and write index which are wrapped when reaching the end of the array. Size is defined as:

```
def size = writeIndex - readIndex + (if (readIndex > writeIndex) array.size else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer to the question's details (but does somewhat answer the question's title), `List.fill(1000){0}` would create a `List` of length 1000 with initial value of `0`, which is from

[Scala - creating a type parametrized array of specified length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413507/scala-creating-a-type-parametrized-array-of-specified-length)