# Scala - creating a type parametrized array of specified length

Tags: arrays, scala, type-parameter

If in Scala IDE try the following:

```
val chars = Array[Char](256)
```

it is all fine. But if I do this:

```
val len = 256
val chars = Array[Char](len)
```

it says that it expects a `Char` instead of `len`? Why? I expect the behavior to be the same! Why does it think that I want to put that thing in the array instead of specifying it's size? As far as I know, there is no constructor for arrays that takes a single argument to place it inside the array.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
val chars = Array[Char](256)
```

This works because 256 treated as a `Char` and it creates one-element array (with code 256)

```
val len = 256
val chars = Array[Char](len)
```

Here len is `Int`, so it fails

To create array of specified size you need something like this

```
val chars = Array.fill(256){0}
```

where `{0}` is a function to produce elements

If the contents of the Array don't matter you can also use `new` instead of `fill`:

```
val chars = new Array[Char](256)
```

Comment: If the contents of the Array dont matter you can also use new instead of fill:

    `val chars = new Array[Char](256)`

Answer (score 43):

Use `Array.ofDim[Char](256)`.

See [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array$.html) here.