# Bounded Scala Queue - extended - over ride += or ++=

Tags: scala, queue, maxlength

Using this [message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918731/maximum-length-for-scala-queue/6920366#6920366), I've extended a mutable queue in order to have a fixed-length queue.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class FiniteQueue[A](limit: Int) extends mutable.Queue[A] {

  override def enqueue(elems : A*) = {
    super.enqueue()
    while(super.size > limit) {
      super.dequeue()
    }
  }
}
```

So this will work when I use

```
val myQueue: FiniteQueue[Double] = new FiniteQueue(3)
myQueue.enqueue(1) //myQueue = {1}
myQueue.enqueue(2) //myQueue = {1,2}
myQueue.enqueue(3) //myQueue = {1,2,3}
myQueue.enqueue(4) //myQueue = {2,3,4}
```

If I do

```
myQueue += (1,2,3,4)
```

then I end up with `myQueue = {1,2,3,4}` rather than `{2,3,4}`

So how do I override the `+=` functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `+=` method from trait `Growable` from package `scala.collection.generic`. Note, if value to add is list, then directly call `++=` method to add the elements : `this ++= elems`, instead calling `super.enqueue(elems)` will not work. After adding elements in your override `+=` method, you need to check the size constraints in order to maintain allowed limt of queue.

```
  class FiniteQueue[A](limit: Int) extends mutable.Queue[A] {

    override def enqueue(elems: A*): scala.Unit = {
      this ++= elems
      while(super.size > limit) {
        super.dequeue()
      }
    }

    override def +=(elem1: A, elem2: A, elems: A*): FiniteQueue.this.type = {
      enqueue(elem1)
      enqueue(elem2)
      this ++= elems
      while(super.size > limit) {
        super.dequeue()
      }
      this
    }
  }

  val myQueue: FiniteQueue[Double] = new FiniteQueue(3)
  println("Queue => " +myQueue)
  myQueue.enqueue(1) //myQueue = {1}
  println("Queue => " +myQueue)
  myQueue.enqueue(2) //myQueue = {1,2}
  println("Queue => " +myQueue)
  myQueue.enqueue(3) //myQueue = {1,2,3}
  println("Queue => " +myQueue)
  myQueue.enqueue(4) //myQueue = {2,3,4}
  println("Queue => " +myQueue)
  myQueue += (4,5,6,7,8)
  println("Queue => " +myQueue)

//Result:
Queue => Dual()
Queue => Dual(1.0)
Queue => Dual(1.0, 2.0)
Queue => Dual(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
Queue => Dual(2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
Queue => Dual(6.0, 7.0, 8.0))
```